# Limiting radio button selection across groups

Tags: jquery, radio-button, limit

I know how to limit the number of checkboxes a user can choose, but am lost on how to do this with multiple groups of radio buttons.

This is the scenario. The first set of radio buttons allows the user to select a number - anything from 1 to 6. I am getting that value like this:

```
    $('#input_3_1 input').on('change', function() {
    var selectedVal = "";
    var selected = $("#input_3_1 input[type='radio']:checked");
    if (selected.length > 0) {
        selectedVal = selected.val();
    }
    });
```

After that there are a series of radio groups, each with multiple options, like so:

```
    <div id="input_3_2" class="limit-this">
    <input name="input_2" type="radio" value="Choice 1">
    <input name="input_2" type="radio" value="Choice 2">
    <input name="input_2" type="radio" value="Choice 3">
    </div>

    <div id="input_3_3" class="limit-this">
    <input name="input_3" type="radio" value="Choice 1">
    <input name="input_3" type="radio" value="Choice 2">
    <input name="input_3" type="radio" value="Choice 3">
    </div>
```

And so on for a variable number of fields, which can be up to 10.

I need the user to by able to select only the number of choices selected in the first field across ALL of these other fields.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: There's no way to uncheck all the choices in a radio group. What is the user supposed to do if he hits the limit, and then wants to uncheck one of the old groups so he can select something from another group?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I had it working I realised that would be an issue. Thanks for raising it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.limit-this input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    var a = $('.limit-this input[type="radio"]:checked').length;
    if(a>selectedVal) if($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

See the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w5vsksat/1/)

In [DEMO2](https://jsfiddle.net/w5vsksat/2/) I have enabled unchecking currently checked items for the case user changes his mind and wants to make another selection:

```
$('.limit-this input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    var a = $('.limit-this input[type="radio"]:checked').length;
    var b = ($(this).is(':checked')?1:0);
    if(a>selectedVal){ if($(this).is(':checked')){ $(this).removeAttr('checked');}}
    else{

     if($(this).is(':checked')&&$(this).data('val')==1) {$(this).removeAttr('checked');
         $(this).data('val', 0);  
     }else
       $(this).data('val', b);    
    }

});
```

Comment: I edited my code and added a demo please have a look

Comment: That's absolutely perfect! Thanks for taking the trouble to create a demo, it really helped.

Comment: you are welcome. do you need to enabled unchecking for the user as Barmar mentioned in the comments?

Comment: @Katherine I added another demo that enables user to uncheck an item and change his/her decision

Comment: Are you psychic? I was just trying to figure out how to do exactly that!

Comment: something like that ;) when you do something you must complete it

Comment: Well, I honestly could not be more grateful

Comment: you are welcome. I'm always here to help. If you need help anytime. just drop me a line.